# SAS ODS escape character macro variable error

Tags: sas, sas-macro

The SAS v9.4 documentation lists an automatic macro variable [`&sysodsescapechar`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/68140/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0qzibu4f9o7rnn1d7fh5lnlwa88.htm) which contains the current ODS escape character, assigned using `ods escapechar=`.

Whenever I try to view the macro variable using a `%put` statement, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Open code statement recursion detected.
```

This happens when open code erroneously causes a macro statement to call another macro statement.

I've tried all of the following:

```
%put &=sysodsescapechar.;
%put %nrbquote(&sysodsescapechar.);
%put %superq(sysodsescapechar);
```

They all result in the same error.

When I try to view the macro variable using a data step, it appears to be empty.

```
data test;
    esc = "&sysodsescapechar.";
    put esc=;
run;
```

If the macro variable actually is empty, why do I get open code statement recursion errors? The `%put` statement on its own is valid, so putting an empty variable shouldn't be an issue.

Any guidance here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is the escape char seems to need a close parentheses. For example:

```
%put %superq(SYSODSESCAPECHAR););
```

> ;

It escapes the `)` , which means now you have

```
%put superq(;);
```

In your first example, it's a little trickier because a semicolon by itself doesn't seem to be escaped so you have to provide a close parentheses:

```
%put &SYSODSESCAPECHAR.)x;
```

> x

That works, for example.  I'm not sure if it's only close paren or other things that would also allow it to stop trying to escape, but that's the only thing I can tell works.

You can look at the actual value of the macro variable in `SASHELP.VMACRO`; it's not ' ' (which is indeed what gets passed to the data step even with SYMGET, but it's clearly parsed).  In that table it is '03'x, which looks like a uppercase L in the upper half of the character.  That is the "End of Text" control character.  I suspect the behavior in the editor when using this in text (in a macro variable) is simply a behavior of the editor - '03'x is not representable on many editors (if I try to paste it here, for example, it isn't displayed, but does exist as something I can backspace over with zero width).  SAS is clearly capable of dealing with a 'normal' ods escapechar but isn't capable of dealing with '03'x in the same fashion.

Comment: Thanks, Joe. Something to note is that if I assign the ODS ESCAPECHAR to something other than the default, which you pointed out is '03'x, using `%superq(sysodsescapechar););` gives me an error on the second close paren. Also, if I use something other than the default, I get no recursion errors with my original statements.

Comment: Also it amuses me that SAS isn't capable of dealing with '03'x as you said, yet it's the default escape character...

Comment: Of course if it's assigned to something you get an error on the second close paren; you could do something like `%put %superq(sysodsescapechar);*);` (add an asterisk, which becomes a comment if it is defined properly).  SAS of course can handle '03'x in the SAS engine - it's the editor that isn't handling it properly, I believe.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the log that isn't handling it properly? Why the editor?

Comment: No, the log is not capable of generating errors in and of itself.  I probably shouldn't say editor, as technically the editor doesn't see the symbol; it's probably the macro processor which is being tripped up.  I don't know for sure.  But it's something at or before the SAS language compiler, and my feeling is that it's not the language compiler itself - it's the word scanner or the macro processor, most likely, one or the other not handling the '03'x character properly (or handling it the way it's supposed to be handled - that is a control character so there may be some old mainframeness).

Comment: Okay. Thanks for all of the information. As always, it's much appreciated.